# Unable to view inline images in the body of a markdown file in GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, gatsby

I am trying to display images from a Markdown file especially from the body of the markdown file but unable to see them.

I am using the recommended plugin configuration by the official GatsbyJS documentation for embedding images in Markdown files. However, I am unable to achieve the same. I can view the images from the frontmatter using GraphQL queries but unable to view the body inline images in the markdown file.

```
const guid = process.env.NETLIFY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID;

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Apple Software',
    description: 'my theme',
    contact: {
      phone: '+91 999999999',
      email: 'info@abcxyz.com',
    },
    menuLinks: [
      {
        name: 'Services',
        link: '/services',
      },
      {
        name: 'Team',
        link: '/team',
      },
      {
        name: 'Testimonials',
        link: '/testimonials',
      },
      {
        name: 'Blog',
        link: '/blog',
      },
      {
        name: 'Contact',
        link: '/contact',
      },
      {
        name: 'Work',
        link: '/work',
      },
      {
        name: 'Courses',
        link: '/carousel',
      },
      {
        name: 'Careers',
        link: '/careers',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    'gatsby-transformer-json',
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
        name: 'data',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
        name: 'images',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics',
      options: {
        trackingId: guid ? guid : 'UA-XXX-1',
        // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
        head: false,
      },
    },
  `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    options: {
      plugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
          options: {
            // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
            // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
            // base for generating different widths of each image.
            maxWidth: 590,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1200,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

and here is the markdown file

```
---
path: '/services/accounting'
title: 'Accounting'
date: 2018-11-18T12:33:46+10:00
image: 'services/default.png'
---

Lorem markdownum aequalis strigis. _Saetigeri iubeas_, vultu huic alvum nondum
de obside ut laniavit arbor palmis, cum quin. Rupes vetat videndo, armigerae
crimen habet Priamum nec.

## Ne verba patulosque numen vix libet

![Default Image](./default.png)


Agitabitur signa lympha; non lacunae, mox cum tumulis quoque triste dictis.
Ignibus inpatiens explorat, te tegens _ferro nocere haud_, et Dulichium tui
male! Quo sed [fuit flexit et](#vexant-achivi) hic die solido, gloria?

1. Cum det dixit Parcarum qui spemque est
2. Exit ex huic
3. Quod consiste agitataque claustraque vicina videt lacertis
4. Loquor videt
5. Ardua non igne caelesti coniugis cognovi diversorum
6. Per nunc pariterque saeva vindicet

Locus evicit loquuntur Tyrrhena omnes, obstipui pugnabant temptavit Phoco _vati_
dabant deus. Memorata haberet sepulcrales gentisque dum sic, in flumina templa!
Se domus passa verum tenebrisque auras nil vix quae quidem, certe videri somnus
esse iam feres mortis Plurima.

## Postquam tamen

Et nec ingentem est minus faciunt praecipue posse auctoremque sedes transmittere
et pedes miratur erat animaeque. Tellus admonuit humanam funes, sagittis et
licet! Inserui quamvis Clymeni.

- Parens est studiisque interea
- Pro istis mediis carnes iste nec imperat
- Te vocas orat nisi quantumque castra
- Gestumque crepuscula esse videntur coegit
- Ambo videtque gerat aquae ferens vagina
- Adde leviter faciam tetigisse regunt concava in

Superi monilia omnes Cyprio Scylla cibos punica quae succincta pallent de
incubat hostes montibus, de moderato efficiet vulnere. Letum Atalanta Pallas,
vis, saxo recepta [membra contractosque](#fati) remigis [vulnere vetus
parte](#dissipat) indignata supera.
```

The image in the frontmatter (Header) is working fine. But the same image (default.png) is not showing up from the body of this markdown file.